# how to change code to retrieve particular column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**I have a list of data in datagridview. For example, one column is named Class (each row has a different value, see below), is it possble that to have a combo box, that contains all of the possible record Class values in the combo box? **It should be have a list of 6A, 6B, 6C***
If more classes are added to the database later (example 6D), these should also be in the combobox.*

A view of datagridview

```
Class              Name

6A                  Jane,14 May 1980;Mary,4 June 1980; 
6B                  leen, 31 May 1980; Peter 6 Jan 1980;
6C                  Eillen, 19 Aug 1980; Yvwon, 28 Mar 1980;
6D                  Evan, 24 Dec 1980; Ivan, 20 Nov 1980;
```

**Here is the code i found, but how do I change it to what i want?**

```
var input = Convert.ToString(datagridview1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
var resultList = Regex.Matches(input, **@".*?,(.*?),.*?;")**
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(arg => arg.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();



// bind to a combobox
comboBox1.DataSource = resultList;
```

Comment: anyone know how to change, i seriously need help in this!

Comment: Can you inspect the resultList variable and let us know if it's getting the correct values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a Windows Forms app then you can create a class, similar to

```
class Obj {
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

then create a list of objects:

```
var list = new List<Obj>();
list.Add(new Obj() { Class = "6A", Data = "Jane,14 May 1980;Mary,4 June 1980;" });
// continue adding to the list here
```

and then

```
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Class";
```

And finally hook your `comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` to an event and grab the `comboBox1.SelectedItem`, cast it to Obj and you're good.

Comment: but i not using hard coded, i have a datasource, how am i going to incorperate with your code?

Comment: @cutexxxpies: you will substitute the code for the hard-coded list elements with whatever method you are using to query, say from a data source. Your original question is not clear that this is the problem. You may need to clearly identify 2 problems in your original question.

Comment: @IAstract , basically i have a database bind to datagridview which is something like i show in the question, however, i want the class to be show in the combo box, but not in hard coded way, as if there is more class added, the combo box will auto updated itself to get, then now the problem is code given by Sergei Z how am i going to change it, regarding you what you say can show me

Comment: @cutexxxpies: whenever you "bind your database" to the datagridview, why don't you bind the combobox right there as well? At that point the only thing would be to set the `comboBox1.DisplayMember` to the correct field in your datasource.

Comment: @Sergei Z can show me what you mean? cause i never try using before the binding the combo box...so what you mean is this comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Class"; //this class that you declare here is the database field name??

Comment: @IAbstract or @Sergei Z what you mean by hook your comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged to an event and grab the comboBox1.SelectedItem, cast it to Obj and you're good?